# getServerSession is null or undefined ONLY when deployed

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, next-auth

My nextauth route:

```
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { connectToDB } from "@/utils/database";
import User from "@/models/user";

const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],

  session: {
    maxAge: 10 * 60,
  },

  callbacks: {
    async session({session}) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
    const sessionUser = await User?.findOne({ email: session.user.email })
    session.user.id = sessionUser._id;
    return session
    },

    async signIn({ profile }) {
      try {
        await connectToDB();

        // check if user already exists
        const userExists = await User?.findOne({
          email: profile.email,
        });

        // if not, create a new user
        if (!userExists) {
          await User?.create({
            email: profile.email,
          });
        }

        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
};


const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST, authOptions };`
```

Where I'm trying to access getServerSession:

```
import { authOptions } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import SectionWrapper from "@/components/SectionWrapper";

const TaskCard = dynamic(() => import("@/components/ui/TaskCard/TaskCard"));
const Button = dynamic(() => import("@/components/ui/Button/Button"), {
  ssr: false,
});


async function loadTasks() {
  try {
    const res = await import("../api/tasks/route");
    const data = await (await res.GET()).json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error and provide user-friendly feedback
    console.error("Error loading TASKS:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to load tasks. Please try again later.");
  }
}

export default async function page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions); // this returns a session if the user is signed in ONLY in development but ALWAYS returns undefined when I deploy it to vercel.

  if (!session) {
    return <>Not Signed In</>; 
  }

  const tasks = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await loadTasks()));

  return (
    <SectionWrapper className="custom-screen">
...Code to be Displayed
    </SectionWrapper>
  );
}
```

My api route:

```
import Task from "@/models/Task";
import { connectToDB } from "@/utils/database";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions); // this DOESN'T return null if the user is signed in

    if (!session) {
      return unauthenticatedResponse(); 
    }

    await connectToDB();
    const userId = session?.user?.id;
    const tasks = await Task.find({ userId });
    return NextResponse.json(tasks);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return internalServerErrorResponse();
  }
}

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const body = await request.json();
    const newTask = new Task(body);
    const savedTask = await newTask.save();
    return NextResponse.json(savedTask);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return badRequestResponse("Invalid request data");
  }
}

function unauthenticatedResponse() {
  return NextResponse.json(
    { message: "User is not authenticated." },
    { status: 401 }
  );
}

function internalServerErrorResponse() {
  return NextResponse.json(
    { error: "Internal server error" },
    { status: 500 }
  );
}

function badRequestResponse(errorMessage) {
  return NextResponse.json(
    { error: errorMessage },
    { status: 400 }
  );
}
```

The api endpoints apparently work even in production in the route.js files which also use getServerSession to access the session. In addition, useSession also works both in development and production. But what's more confusing is the getServerSession in page.js returns a session if the user is signed ONLY in development mode but ALWAYS returns undefined when I deploy it to vercel.

I'm stuck on this and I really need help. Please give your suggestions.

I atleast expected getServerSession to be unable to work in both development and production. But the problem occurs only in production.